# Zend controller error

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have been using ZF for a while now and done some numerous projects using the command line which I normally use to create projects/controllers and forms, but recently I have encounted this error and can't seem to overcome it can somebody please help or provide solutions on how to encounter it.

```
An error occurred
Page not found
Exception information:

Message: Invalid controller specified (industrialsites)

Stack trace:

#0 C:\xampp\library\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Controller\Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#1 C:\xampp\library\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#2 C:\xampp\library\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\portal-gep-2\public\index.php(26): Zend_Application->run()
#4 {main}  

Request Parameters:
array (
  'controller' => 'industrialsites',
  'action' => 'insertIS',
  'lang' => 'en',
  'module' => 'admin',
)
```

Take note this is the path I want it to follow : http://gep2.local/admin/industrialsites/insertIS but when i click on the link item it goes here http://gep2.local/admin/industrial-sites/industrial. I added the acl in my authentication folder but still I get the same error.

Comment: check the name of controller I think you have `IndustrialSites` instead of `Industrialsites`. Ensure `s` is in small letters.

Comment: checked everything seems fine but I think the was another controller or action before this one so i will search for it and try to redirect it to my contoller and action i just created